# How to monitor Windows bandwidth over a graph?

Tags: windows, display, bandwidth, resources

Windows Resource Monitor shows me a graph of bandwidth for the past 60 seconds only. Is there any way to monitor the bandwidth for a longer period but every second included just like the Resource Monitor does itself?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bandwidth+monitor

Comment: Didnt feel any ‘tool for job’.